# Make triangle pattern in java

Tags: java

I am trying to make this pattern in java:

```
*
* * *
* * * * *
* * *
*
```

Here is what I have right now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(i<j){
                System.out.print(" ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated....

Comment: Think in terms of a 5x5 truth table. Will allow you to print any 5x5 dot-style shape.

Comment: Why do you need to print out spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int width = Math.min(i, size - 1 - i) * 2 + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the int width part?

Comment: Another (clearer to me) way to express `Math.min(i, size-1-i)` is `maxWidth-Math.abs(maxWidth-i)` where `maxWidth = size/2`.

Comment: i would give triangle |\ (base on the bottom), size - 1 - i would give one like `|/` (base on top) and min gives the intersection of these two which is `|>`. The ending is to expand it horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        int n = 1 + 2 * (2 - Math.abs(2 - i));
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            System.out.print("* ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is why did you assume that we should be adding 1 and times that whole thing by 2?

Comment: @user4100421 because you want at least one star and you are growing (shrinking) each subsequent row by two stars.

Answer (score 1):

You have done very well so far.

Now all you have to do is calculate the number of "needed" spaces to put in front of each string.  After adding them, you will have the "full" solution.

Answer (score 0):

It may work in this way also.

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n=sc.nextInt();
  int b=0;
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
  for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
   System.out.print("*");
   if(j!=i){
     System.out.print(" ");
       }
       }
    System.out.println();   
        }
    for(int i=n-1;i>=1;i--){
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
      System.out.print("*");
    if(j!=i){
     System.out.print(" ");
        }
            }
     System.out.println();
      }
```